# How to track several catagories for a product with Google Tag Manager and GA Enhanced Ecommerce?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

On my website, I have products (actually services) that can each fall into several categories (up to 5 categories each).

Whenever a service is purchased, how can I track its categories using Google Tag Manager? How can I pass this information in the data layer?

I've read in some places that I will have to concatenate all categories into 1 string, but I'm not sure this is the right approach.

Any recommendation for implementing this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read in some places that I will have to concatenate all
>   categories into 1 string, but I'm not sure this is the right approach.

Well, not quite.  The [documentation for EEC](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-data) says about categories:

> **category** - The category to which the product belongs (e.g. Apparel).
>   Use / as a delimiter to specify up to 5-levels of hierarchy (e.g.
>   Apparel/Men/T-Shirts).

If you concatenate up to five categories with a slash as delimiter you can access the individual parts with the dimensions "product category 1" to  "product category 5". However this is meant for hierarchies (so the metrics for "product category 1" will aggregate the metrics for the lower tier of the hierarchy). It is not intended for individual categories.

You could use [product scoped custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828#example-product) to store additional categories.

If you indeed use a concatenated string as category you could use [Google Data Studios](https://datastudio.google.com/) to create your reports, and use a [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) to split your category string into distinct dimensions.

So there are ways, but nothing really out of the box.